# How to refactor collection of List<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm wondering if there is a better way to shorten my code or refactor it to maintainable or usable code. Instead of doing List then name so on.. What can I do to improve to my code more meaningful instead doing lot of stuff like List. If there is a good approach to do it? To create it as a helper.

The purpose of this code is storing the data per day each month, expecting they're are inside a loop. They're populated by a data per day.

```
var outputPerDays = new List<OutputPerDay>();

            var day1 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day2 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day3 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day4 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day5 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day6 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day7 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day8 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day9 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day10 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day11 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day12 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day13 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day14 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day15 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day16 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day17 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day18 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day19 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day20 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day21 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day22 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day23 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day24 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day25 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day26 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day27 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day28 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day29 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day30 = new List<Pricing>();
            var day31 = new List<Pricing>();
 [Serializable]
    public class OutputPerDay
    {
        public List<Pricing> Day1 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day2 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day3 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day4 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day5 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day6 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day7 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day8 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day9 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day10 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day11 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day12 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day13 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day14 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day15 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day16 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day17 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day18 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day19 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day20 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day21 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day22 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day23 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day24 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day25 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day26 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day27 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day28 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day29 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day30 { get; set; }
        public List<Pricing> Day31 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could `OutputPerDay` contain a single `List<Pricing>[]` (i.e. array of lists)? Rather than 31 separate properties?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of this code, what is being stored in the collection and how it is going to be used?

Comment: Dictionary<int, List<Pricing>> could be helpful depending how you initialize/use the values.

Comment: @ShaneRay how to use Dictionary<int, List<Pricing>>?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class OutputPerDay
{
    public List<string>[] _pricesPerDay = new List<string>[3];

    public OutputPerDay()
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
        {
            _pricesPerDay[0] = new List<string>();
        }
    }

    public List<string> Day1 => _pricesPerDay[0];
    public List<string> Day2 => _pricesPerDay[1];
    public List<string> Day3 => _pricesPerDay[2];
}
```